# CgridView should be filled with Mongo data- YII

Tags: yii

Im trying to populate `Cgridview` with Mongo data, but getting error `"Undefined offset: 0"`
Here is my coding,

```
    $sql="SELECT name FROM CRM_Field Where crm_base_contact_id = ".$base;
    $names =Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql)->query()-> readAll();
    $mongo = new Mongo( Yii::app()->mongodb->connectionString);
    $collection = $mongo->test->crm_contact_tmp;
    $mongocol = $mongo->test->crm_contact_tmp->find(array('crm_base_contact_id' => array('$in' => array($base))));
    $arrayDataProvider = new CArrayDataProvider (iterator_to_array($mongocol) );
?>

<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id' =>'BCImported-grid',
    'dataProvider' =>$arrayDataProvider,
    'columns' => $names,
)); ?>
```

Can anyone suggest the correct way to do this? Im getting empty grid but with number of records in grid shows correct, but no data displays!!!

Comment: take a look here: http://www.yiiplayground.com/index.php?r=UiModule/dataview/gridViewArray, and see how the columns array must be populated.

Comment: can you point out where im doing wrong??im newbie to yii...

Comment: What's the array `iterator_to_array($mongocol)` returns look like?  [CArrayDataProvider](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CArrayDataProvider#rawData-detail) requires that rawData have zero-based integer keys . . .

Comment: it prints like this=====>>> array(1) { ["52d4d0a39a96b87009000001"]=> array(5) { ["_id"]=> object(MongoId)#226 (1) { ["$id"]=> string(24) "52d4d0a39a96b87009000001" } ["Name"]=> string(3) "XXX" ["DOB"]=> string(9) "12-Aug-80" ["Age"]=> string(2) "26" ["crm_base_contact_id"]=> string(4) "1576" }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data you're getting back from mongo doesn't have zero-based integer keys, which [CArrayDataProvider](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CArrayDataProvider#rawData-detail) requires.  Looks like it's got arrays as keys.  I think setting the [use_keys](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iterator-to-array.php) parameter to false should solve this, i.e.:

```
$arrayDataProvider = new CArrayDataProvider (iterator_to_array($mongocol, false) );
```

Comment: Thank you @ernie i added 'keyField' param like this==>$arrayDataProvider = new CArrayDataProvider (iterator_to_array($mongocol, false),'keyField'=>'Name' ) now works but one column value not populating ie., last column in grid why???

Comment: If i use array('Name','DOB','Age','Addr') in grid 'Columns' im getting all data in grid but if i use $names array last column data not showing in grid...how this could happen????